# logistic regression for advertising analysis in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

I have a data set where I am trying to test if having a 7 day advertising period is better than having a 5 day advertising period. I feel that logistic regression would be the best way to test this out. I ran the tests for 2 weeks each. I have data like traffic, signups, attrition.

Here is what the data look like:

```
              5d         7d  greater (does the 7d have atleast 5% more than 5d)
Traffic     179650  196395   1
subscribers 437899  442068   0
attrition   2304    2376     0
signups     5039    6246     1
```

1 means yes and 0 means no.

I ran this code in R:

```
fit2<-glm(greater~X5d + X7d, data=logr2, family = "binomial")
```

then

```
predict(fit2, data=logr2, type = "response")
```

My output is :

```
 1            2            3            4 
1.000000e+00 6.753019e-13 1.386707e-10 1.000000e+00
```

or

```
> round(predict(fit2, data=logr2, type = "response"))
1 2 3 4 
1 0 0 1
```

How can I run it such that I get only 1 output to tell me 1 or 0 (IE does the 7 day have a greater than 5 % overall increase?)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're running your model correctly. You really only have output (target) variables with no predictors.

Comment: Perhaps instead of seeing if there is a 5% increase between 7d and 5d, I should do a statistical significance test instead. And 1=yes there is statistical significance and 0= no significance?

Comment: You are asking yourself is 7 better than 5. I would construct two models and compare them, say via AIC. That being said, I think this question belongs on crossvalidated.com.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It doesn't, as it concerns implementation details, not statistics. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused the argument names of the `predict` function (see the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html)), try this:

```
predict(fit2, newdata=logr2, type = "response")
```

The strange output comes from the fact that you're giving the training data as the input to predict, which doesn't really make sense. Try some fresh data point, like this:

```
input = data.frame(X5d = 123, X7d = 22)
predict(fit2, newdata=logr2, type = "response")
```

Result:

> 1
>
> 2.775557e-13

which means that it's `1` with probability almost `0`.

If you give an exact point from your data set:

```
input = data.frame(X5d = 179650, X7d = 196395)
predict(fit2, newdata=input, type = "response")
```

Result:

> 1
>
> 1

So it's `1` with probability `1`.

You can check other data points from your training set - the results are perfect, as for such a few training data samples your fit is ideal.

You can find a simple, similar example [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/logistic-regression/estimated-logistic-regression-equation).

Comment: I still get the same thing:                                               `1            2            3            4` 
`1.000000e+00 6.753019e-13 1.386707e-10 1.000000e+00`